# How to find the restrictions of side length on an obtuse triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry, inequality, geometric-inequalities

**Question**:

*In Triangle ABC, the angle ∠ABC is an obtuse angle. 
The Side AB is 1cm, and the side BC is 3cm.
Side AC is (3x+10)/(x+3) cm
Find the restriction(s) on x*.

I have tried a few different methods, such as using the cosine rule, but they have iether yoelded the wrong answer, or have taken a VERY long time to solve. What would be the simplest, easiest way to solve this problem?

Thank you for helping x

Answer (score 3):

Use 2 conditions:

Since $\angle ABC$ is obtuse, so $$\left({3x+10\over x+3}\right)^2\gt1^2+3^2$$
And triangle inequality$$0\lt{3x+10\over x+3}\lt 1+3$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got an answer of -3 < x < -2, but how can i check this solution to make sure it is correct?

Comment: @StephanieCook Take random numbers in $[-3,-2]$ to compute value of $AC$ and draw them (by hand or by some software) and check yourself.. And please accept my answer if you liked it..:-)

Comment: Ive noticed one thing. The inequalities that you created dont account for the fact that a side length must be greater than 0 cm (cannot have negative lengths). does that mean we need ANOTHER inequality?!

Comment: E.g. If AC² is 16, then AC could be -4 or 4

Comment: @StephanieCook Happy?

Answer (score 0):

Put $|AC|=:s$. Then $s^2=1^2+3^2-6\cos\beta>10$, and the triangle inequality gives $s\leq1+3$, hence $s^2<16$, so that we now face
$$10<\left({3x+10\over x+3}\right)^2<16\ .$$
Multiplying through by $(x+3)^2>0$ we get
$$10x^2+60x+90<9x^2 +60x +100<16x^2+96 x+144\ ,\tag{1}$$
or
$$x^2<10<7x^2+36 x+54\ .$$
The equation $7x^2+36x+44=0$ is solved by $x_1:=-{44\over14}$ and $x_2:=-2$. It follows that the right inequality in $(1)$ is fulfilled for $x<x_1$ and for $x>x_2$ (note that the forbidden $x=-3$ does not belong to the feasible region). Since $\sqrt{10}\doteq3.162>3.142\doteq{44\over14}$ we conclude that the set $S$ of allowed $x$ is the union of two intervals as follows:
$$S=\ \left]-\sqrt{10}, -{44\over14}\right[\ \ \cup\ \ \bigl]-2,\sqrt{10}\bigr[\ .$$